# How to make this circle revolve around this circle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, dom

- I am trying to move blue circle around the red circle and draw on canvas using only red circle.

Problems:

- I was unable to understand how can I maintain centers of two circles while blue circle is revolving around the red circle and moving at the same time.
- how can I draw using only red circle without making the blue circle drawing while it is revolving around the red circle.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let positionX = 100;
let positionY = 100;
let X = 50;
let Y = 50;
let angle = 0;

function circle(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, 20, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function direction(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(positionX, positionY, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function animate(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    circle();
    direction();
    positionX += 0.5 * Math.sin(angle);
    positionY += 0.5 * Math.cos(angle);
    angle += 0.1;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```css
#canvas1{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas basics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In case it interest you check my [repo](https://github.com/Florian-crg/eklo) you can use it and adapt it to make a solar system using [renature](https://formidable.com/open-source/renature/) [Working exemple of the repo](https://eklo.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this ? - I've animated the red circ to move right . The blue circ orbits .

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let positionX = 100;
let positionY = 100;
let X = 50;
let Y = 50;
let angle = 0;

function circle(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, 20, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function direction(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(positionX, positionY, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function animate(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    circle();
    direction();
    positionX = X + 35 * Math.sin(angle);
    positionY = Y + 35 * Math.cos(angle);
    X+=1 ;

    angle += 0.1;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```css
#canvas1{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas basics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I meant to add - I only altered the animate() function slightly.

Comment: Thank you so much. can you show how to draw on the canvas while the red circle is moving. (i.e only with red circle not with blue circle around it)

Answer (score 0):

I did not get all your problem clearly, but to revolve blue circle around red you just need to properly set values.

UPDATED: added rotation to red circle + minor description in code comments.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// Here we set our start positions of
// circles. Keep in mind, that they will rotare not
// around it's centers, they will START rotation path
// from their centers
let positionX = 30;
let positionY = 59;
let X = 70;
let Y = 70;
let angle = 0;
let angle2 = 360;

function circle(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, 20, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function direction(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(positionX, positionY, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function animate(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    circle();
    direction();
    // Basically you use geometry and math,
    // you can search for Sin and Cos online.
    // Here we calculate angle position on each frame
    //
    // Calc animation for first circle
    // It (animation path) starts from the center of circle and goes counterclockwise
    // And returns to its position after 360 deg.
    positionX += 4 * Math.sin(angle);
    positionY += 4 * Math.cos(angle);
    // Calc animation for second circle
    // Same as previous but with less amount
    // And our start position (angle2) is 360
    X += 1 * Math.sin(angle2);
    Y += 1 * Math.cos(angle2);
    // Set angle of orbit - increase value each frame
    angle += 0.1;
    angle2 += 0.1;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```css
#canvas1{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas basics</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which values and what is proper?

Comment: How can we bind those two two circle centers while moving? simply adding `X+=1` in `function animate()` makes only one circle moves.

Comment: @harsha check update to answer - I've added some description.